# Getting "Object is possibly 'null'. TS2531" on a form input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to build a simple form to capture email and password for a new user signing up on Firebase, I'm using React with Typescript and I'm getting the error "Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531" on the following section of the code:

```
 <form onSubmit={(event) => { this.handleSignUp({event, email: this._email.current.value, password: this._password.current.value})}}>
```

In particular it's the `this._email.current.value` and `this._password.current.value` that are throwing this error.

I've dug around about both the error code and type scripting and it's something to do with the "strictNullChecks" on the typescript, but I don't really want to turn that option off, and I don't think I have enough skill or understanding of coding to know how to get around this. Even though I do understand that a form can be submitted with empty values, I am checking later with the firebase auth to make sure that there are strings with more than 4 characters.

Below is the code for the whole react component.

```
interface IHandleSubmitNewUserFunc {
    event: any,
    email: any,
    password: any
}

class NewUserSignup extends React.Component {
     constructor(props: any) {
         super(props);
         this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
     }

    handleSignUp(input: IHandleSubmitNewUserFunc) {
        input.event.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = input;
        if (email.length < 4 && email != null) {
            alert('Please enter an email address.');
            return;
        }
        if (password.length < 4 && password != null) {
            alert('Please enter a password.');
            return;
        }
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                alert('The password is too weak.');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    private _email = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
    private _password = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

    render() {
        return <div>
            <div className="signup-modal-container">
                <div className="identity-panel">
                    <img src={logo}></img>
                    <form onSubmit={(event) => { this.handleSignUp({event, email: this._email.current.value, password: this._password.current.value})}}>
                        <div className="form-flex-container">
                            <div className="signup-item">
                                <h2>
                                    Sign Up
                                </h2>
                                <label htmlFor="email" id="email">
                                    Email:
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="signup-item">
                                <div className="input-container">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ref={this._email}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="signup-item">
                                <label htmlFor="password">
                                    Password:
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="signup-item">
                                <div className="input-container">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ref={this._password}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="signup-item">
                                <button type="submit">
                                    Sign Up
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
            NewUserSignup is showing
            </p>

        </div>
    }
}
export default NewUserSignup;
```

I'm not really sure what code I'd need to not throw this error, any advice is aprpeciated.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much as it says. The references are null by default, there's no guarantee that `current` is assigned by the time you access them (as far as the code knows).

You have 2 options:

- Add a truthy check before access `this._email.current` and `this._password.current`.

```
const eCurrent = this._email.current;
const pCurrent = this._password.current;
if (!eCurrent || !pCurrent) {
  // This will probably never happen, to respond to events these will be hooked up.
  return;
}
```

- Use the non-null assertion since you know it's a safe operation: `this._email.current!.value`.

```
// Assert that current won't be null.
const emailValue = this._email.current!.value;
const passwordValue = this._password.current!.value;
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what do those look like exactly? 

My best guess with a truthy operator would be adding the modifying the code as so

```
 <form onSubmit={(event) => { this.handleSignUp(
{event, 
email: () => {if(this._email.current.value){return this._email.current.value}, 
password: () => { if(this._password.current.value){return this._password.current.value} 
})

}}>
```

Comment: I guess I am asking to show a coded example of what that looks like, not because I don't want to do the work, but I literally don't know what a truty check, or a non-null assertion even looks like. I'm googling them now though.